# websvn garbles java source files

Tags: java, svn, webserver, review, source-control

It appears to be attempting to interpolate Javadoc links into standard Java classes, among other things. The resultant output is fairly difficult to read. For instance, I am defining a Queue at one point:

`private Queue replyQueue;`

WebSVN is rendering this as follows (literals included):

`private 1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html">Queue replyQueue;`

Now, it doesn't seem to affect business logic in terms of comparing revision graphs or anything, and presumably this is straightforward misconfiguration, but I've poked around a bit and haven't been able to make much progress. Has anyone else seen -- ideally, repaired -- this issue with garbled Java output from WebSVN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I commented out the following line in `/etc/websvn/config.php` and the issue has resolved itself.

> `//$config->useGeshi();`

Comment: But one seems to loose some syntax colouring this way.

Answer (score 2):

following the recipe mentioned here, this issues was fixed properly in our setup

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/geshi/+bug/843908
(comment by Andreas Schöneck)

> By updating GeSHi to the most recent version (1.0.8.10) I was able to fix this issue.
>
> My steps taken:
>   1. download GeSHi distribution archive, uncompress (you will get a geshi folder)
>   2. backup old /usr/share/php-geshi
>   3. replace old /usr/share/php-geshi with the geshi folder from inside the archive
>   done
>
> URL http://sourceforge.net/projects/geshi/files/geshi/GeSHi%201.0.8.10/

Comment: This helped. Syntax colouring and linking into the java docs works now.